# How to add Upload Button for importing a csv file in the Custom Admin Grid Container in magento 2?

Tags: grid, uicomponent, magento-2.2.5

I wish to add import button in my custom admin grid using ui component, in magento 2.

To add this import button which type of grid is better ? ui component grid or php grid.

Note :

> We can fill the grid **by clicking add new and fill the form** or **by
>   clicking import button and upload csv file**

Please provide me a solution

Answer (score 1):

ui_component is easier..

```
 <fieldset name="Import">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Import</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="import">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Import</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="path/to/controller"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```